# why my Codeigniter database query is only returning one row instead of more?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am querying database for products which is set "enabled" and whose category ID is as input...

But there are two fields in database having same values (enabled and cat. id=7)..
But query result is returning only first row.

How do i get both rows?

Here is my query..

```
function get_cat_products($cat_id)
{
    $this->db->select('product_basic.product_id,product_basic.product_name,product_basic.product_sp,product_images.image1');
    $this->db->from('product_images', 'product_basic');
    $this->db->join('product_basic', 'product_basic.product_id = product_images.product_id');
    $this->db->where('product_basic.product_status','enabled');
    $this->db->where('product_basic.product_cat_id',$cat_id);
    $this->db->limit(2);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: $this->db->limit(2);  may b this is the reason?

Comment: do you have more than single row of data as per your query ?

Comment: print your query and check in database as echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: @Anant i tried it, but it is not working...

Comment: @OwaisArain i have two rows satisfying both conditions

Comment: As @dharmendrachaudhary says print your query and check it on mysql, how many rows is it returning ?

Comment: why you are adding limit in your query?...

Comment: It is returning two products now in mySql ... @dharmendrachaudhary

Comment: Thank you, maybe it was that limit(2) was the problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: Is your problem solved ? @WebFlash

Comment: @OwaisArain yeah.. it is solved.. thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_cat_products($cat_id)
{
    $this->db->select('product_basic.product_id,product_basic.product_name,product_basic.product_sp,product_images.image1');
    $this->db->from('product_images');
    $this->db->join('product_basic', 'product_basic.product_id = product_images.product_id');
    $this->db->where('product_basic.product_status','enabled');
    $this->db->where('product_basic.product_cat_id',$cat_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

try this  ...